# MySql select aggregates from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037027/mysql-select-qualification-expiry-dates) I asked how to return the dates of the LATEST tests passed by each user, based on three tables, **Users**, **Tests** and **Passes**.

```
|--------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|User    |Test A   |Test B   |Test C   |Test D   |Test E   |
|--------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|James   |Null     |6/3/11   |Null     |Null     |4/3/11   |
|Mark    |Null     |1/4/11   |8/5/11   |23/5/10  |Null     |
|--------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
```

The following query was advised:

```
select
  u.username,
  max(case when testid = 1 then datetaken else null end) as A,
  max(case when testid = 2 then datetaken else null end) as B,
  max(case when testid = 3 then datetaken else null end) as C,
  max(case when testid = 4 then datetaken else null end) as D,
  max(case when testid = 5 then datetaken else null end) as E
from users as u left join passes as p on u.userid = p.userid
group by u.userid
```

It turns out that in my actual scenario, I have two Tests tables (say TestsX containing tests A, B and C and TestsY containing tests D and E) and two corresponding passes tables (say PassesX and PassesY).

This is required because the tables have different structures. However, for simplicity here let's say they're identical. They both link to the same Users table. Please could you let me know how to adjust the above select command accordingly, to get the same output (everything in one table)?

Maybe this is achievable with a subquery and union, but I wouldn't know how?

Many thanks (and I hope this makes sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  u.UserName,
  px.TestA,
  px.TestB,
  px.TestC,
  py.TestD,
  py.TestE
FROM Users u
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      UserId,
      MAX(CASE TestId WHEN 1 THEN DateTaken ELSE NULL END) AS TestA,
      MAX(CASE TestId WHEN 2 THEN DateTaken ELSE NULL END) AS TestB,
      MAX(CASE TestId WHEN 3 THEN DateTaken ELSE NULL END) AS TestC
    FROM PassesX
    GROUP BY UserId
  ) px ON u.UserId = px.UserId
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      UserId,
      MAX(CASE TestId WHEN 4 THEN DateTaken ELSE NULL END) AS TestD,
      MAX(CASE TestId WHEN 5 THEN DateTaken ELSE NULL END) AS TestE,
    FROM PassesY
    GROUP BY UserId
  ) py ON u.UserId = py.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select   u.username,   
max(case when px.testid = 1 then px.datetaken else null end) as A,   
max(case when px.testid = 2 then px.datetaken else null end) as B,   
max(case when px.testid = 3 then px.datetaken else null end) as C,   
max(case when py.testid = 4 then py.datetaken else null end) as D,   
max(case when py.testid = 5 then py.datetaken else null end) as E 
from (users as u left join passesX as px on u.userid = px.userid)
      LEFT JOIN passesY as py on u.userid = py.userid) 
group by u.userid
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this. Isn't it really inefficient though??

Comment: I don't think so(unless someone else gives a better answer). To get all data together you need to JOIN tables, then to get the result you want you have to use MAX and CASE statements. This is the simplest and efficient query I can think of. Even the [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) has an example of two joins in a query somewhere.